# Chaining multiple ffmpeg filters into one command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an input.mp4 file, and I want to be able to change the resolution to 640x480, extract the video from 00:17 to 00:27, remove audio stream and convert the result to .avi, all in a single command. How do I do so? I tried multiple ways like the ones below but to no avail.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex “[0:v]trim=start=17:duration=10[tmp];[tmp]scale=640:480[out]” -map [out] out.mp4`

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex “[0:v]scale=640:480,trim=start=17:duration=10” -map [out] out.mp4`

Would appreciate any inputs!

Comment: Your output extension is mp4, change that to avi. Besides that, what's the issue?

Comment: When I tried running on my terminal, it throws this error ```No such filter: '“'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument```

Comment: Replace the fancy quotes with standard double quotes: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=640:480,trim=start=17:duration=10" out.avi`